# A clarification in bitwise operators

Tags: c

I have been performing bitwise operation on a variable.

```
int p=3,q=5;
int a=~p,b=~q; //complement a and b
printf("%d %d\t%d %d",p,a,q,b);
```

The theoretical output for 'b' is 10 and in case if it's signed, it has to be -2. 
But the output is -6.

Can someone explain me the working of it?

Comment: Why is the "theoretical output for b" 10?

Comment: I edited it. It has to be fine now.

Comment: For your *"theoretical 10"* keep in mind that `int` is not just 4 bits in size (Hint: what happens with leading zeros under bitwise NOT?).

Comment: "in case if it's signed" The default `int` type is always signed. Never use bit-wise operators on signed numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~` is the bitwise complement operator in c (or python) which essentially calculates `-x - 1`.

So a table would look like:

```
0  -1
1  -2
2  -3
3  -4 
4  -5 
5  -6
```

In two's complement representation, if a number x's most significant bit is 1, then the actual value would be −(~x + 1).

For instance,

```
0b11110000 = -(~0b1111 + 1) = -(15 + 1) = -16.
```

This is a natural representation of negative numbers, because

```
0000001 =  1
0000000 =  0
1111111 = -1  (wrap around)
1111110 = -2
1111101 = -3 etc.
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement for detail.

Comment: It's not necessarily twos complement in C - it's defined to complement all the sign and value bits, and whether the implementation uses twos complement, ones' complement or sign-magnitude is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is 0b11, so `a` would be (assuming 16-bit int) 0b1111111111111100 = 0xFFFC if unsigned and -3 if signed.

`q` is 0b101, so `b` would be (assuming 16-bit int) 0b1111111111111010 = 0xFFFA if unsigned and -6 if signed.

Comment: You either forgot a bunch of 1s and Fs or you meant 16 when writing 32.

Comment: WHOOPS! You are right. While I prefer 32 bit, I use 16 for making it more readable...

Comment: @unknownDownvoter But is this really a reason to -1? I think the intention became clear enough...

Comment: FYI I haven't been the downvoter, since for me this was not reason enough.

Comment: I didn't suppose so (so I wrote unknownDownvoter ;-) ). And I don't really expect that the downvoter will answer, so my comment was essentially unnecessary...

Answer (score 1):

while taking complement of p(i.e 5), you are expecting it to be 1010. i.e 10. But the the fact is during one's complement operation, all bits are inverted.

Consider this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int p=5,q=3;
int a=~p,b=~q; //complement a and b
printf("%x %x\t%x %x",p,a,q,b);

return 0;
}
```

prints

```
5 fffffffa  3 fffffffc
```

so while printing using %d, sign is considered.